# LESS Syntax Highlighting in Dreamweaver (CodeColoring.XML)?

Tags: xml, less, dreamweaver

I use Adobe CS4 to edit my LESS files.  I would like to modify Dreamweaver to apply correct syntax highlighting to my .LESS files.  I have already set Dreamweaver to highlight my LESS files like CSS.  However, CSS syntax highlighting does not recognize **@variable-names/mixins** **(arguments)** { a:foo; **nested-properties { a:foo }** } or **//end-of-line comments**.  I would like to configure dreamweaver CS4 to highlight these correctly.  How does one modify CodeColoring.XML to allow this?

Comment: These might be helpful (though they are for CS5): http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/extend/dreamweaver_cs5_extending.pdf http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d117f53d62b7-7fc4.html

Comment: I have CS5 and that extension is not working.